# How would I use PHP, MySQL, and Ajax to display data correctly? Link included

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

This is a 3-part question. The URL to the page in question can be see [here](http://tobedetermined.com.nu/etd.html). I only have the skeleton typed up. I hope to figure out how to use the languages PHP, MySQL, and AJAX to finish the page.

1. How would I set the db using MySQL?
2. How would I use the "Select a __" option forms in combination with these languages to have the data display in the columns to the right of them.
3. Does anyone have any actual examples they can link to help me better understand what I'm doing that doesn't involve basically reviewing everything in the languages?

If you guys can help me figure this out, I'd be ever so grateful! Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried yourself? This questions is too general.

I suggest you read this tutorial:
http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

And come back when you can't figure it out.

Comment: Ok. I'm a little stuck... The issue is that all examples I've seen have only one form element on a page that they use AJAX with. I have three forms and I know that there's a way to use one function for all three, but I don't know what to do for it. Would you be willing to help me?

Comment: Sure, can you post a new question with you specific problem incl. code etc?

Comment: I actually have posted it already. :D 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646600/can-i-use-more-than-one-function-in-one-script

Answer (score 0):

The basic tutorial which can help you get started can be found @
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: I agree. That's why I was looking for help elsewhere. If anyone knows of any accurate and simplified, or well-explained resources, please comment.