# Can I use more than one function in one script?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to use Ajax, PHP, and MySQL together to make a form element, drop-down style select input be able to select an option and have the ajax sent data through the script to the database and back to the page to a separate div. I have most of the code for this figured out. My issue now is this.

I have three drop-down menus that 1 would like to have go to this script. It would then go to three different $GET scripts depending on which menu it was selected from.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
{ 
if (str=="")
  { document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return; }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send(); }
</script>
```

The three select elements I have are accompanied with onchange functions.

```
<select name="characters" onchange="showCharacter(this.value)">
<select name="towers" onchange="showTowers(this.value)">
<select name="enemies" onchange="showEnemies(this.value)">
```

The PHP code I have for this script is this:

```
<?php

include("dbinfo.inc.php");

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
mysql_select_db("db1801445-main", $con);
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$q=$_GET["q"];

echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    </tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Idk how else to do this so can you guys help me?

Comment: That indentation style is awful

Comment: Yes... well... I did copy and paste it... I hadn't considered presentation until I could get it to work for me properly.

Comment: It should be part of your actual code anyway. Legible code makes maintainable code. It should be automatic, as you write it.

Comment: I shall edit it to look better then. :)

Comment: You really should use jquery. it'd reduce the ENTIRETY of that xmlhttprequest stuff to just a single `$.get('script.php?q=...', function() { ... });`

Comment: I might try to figure that out. I was hoping to do it without having to add jquery, but I think it'll be worth the investment.

Comment: @MarcB If I could upvote that comment 100 times I would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that using jQuery would make your life easier, but to address your question:

You could make that JS code more general so it would be easier to reuse:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doAjax(ajaxFunction, str)
{ 
if (str=="")
  { document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return; }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str+"func="+ajaxFunction,true);
xmlhttp.send(); }
</script>
```

And then change you PHP do this:

```
<?php
$sFunction  = $_GET["func"];
$sQ =$_GET["q"];

switch($sFunction){

    case 'showUser':
       //code here;
    break;
    case 'showTowers':
       //code here;
    break;
   case 'showEnemies':
       //code here;
    break;
    case 'showCharacters':
       //code here;
    break;
}
```

?>

And back on the frontend:

```
<select name="characters" onchange="doAjax('showCharacter',this.value)">
<select name="towers" onchange="doAjax('showTowers',this.value)">
<select name="enemies" onchange="doAjax('showEnemies',this.value)">
```

Comment: When I try to use the function you gave me, firebug gives me an error saying that "doAjax is not defined". I have all the code you put here in their respective places with urls correctly pointing to the corresponding scripts. How is doAjax undefined? Shouldn't the command be sent to the Ajax script when the onchange event occurs and then it would find where to go for the php script, get the data from the database and then present it on the screen with the Ajax script? I'm almost sure that's how it's supposed to work... I could be wrong, but please correct me if I am. :)

Comment: You are right. Maybe there is an error in the JS that generated the error. Did you check with firebug?

Comment: At the moment all firebug is telling me is this:
function onchange(event) {
doAjax("showTowers", this.value);
}

Comment: I'm trying to see what can fix it, but as it seems, the function doesn't seem to include the XMLHttpRequest();. Also, the var for that isn't declared, so I changed it to be this Var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); in an attempt to see if that would help, but there wasn't any change. I'll comment if I find a fix.

Comment: Well I found my problem. As embarrassed as I am to say, I was calling your script from an external .js file so it was throwing it off, because I guess I didn't point the  inline script to the file correctly. It works fine. Very good work. Thank you.

Comment: I came across another problem. I looked it up on google and on here. I tried a couple of different expressions, but nothing seemed to work. The parameter passes in this format: `2func=showTowers`. What expression in php would make it to where it'll only be a number? I've tried a number of things. I've even made it a string and tried `preg_replace` to replace the characters designated into "". That seemed to have no effect. I'm sure I almost was at the right approached. Can you help me?

Comment: I think its easier if you just open a new question and paste your code. The comments are not suitable for this kind of work

Comment: It prolly is, but I was told I was being a pansy and stupid for apparently not knowing how to do that. :/ Here's the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837083/php-ajax-to-php-parameter-issue) to the question. Please have a look. :)