# PHP: Ajax-to-PHP parameter issue

Tags: php

Using the Ajax code, designated below, in the head of my page, [ETD2.html](http://tobedetermined.com.nu/etd2.html), it'll send a parameter to a php script containing a switch statement. The problem I'm having is that in order for the switch statement to work correctly, the parameter has to include more than just a number, while for the mysql query to run, I need a variable which will be equal to the parameter, although it'll only contain the number in the variable and nothing else.

Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doAjax(ajaxFunction, str)
{ 
if (str=="")
  { document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return; }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str+"func="+ajaxFunction,true);
xmlhttp.send(); }
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

include("dbinfo.inc.php");
$con = mysql_connect(localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $con);
if (!$db_selected)
    {
    die('Could not connect to ' . $database . '<br />' . mysql_errno() . ': ' . mysql_error());
    }

$sFunction  = $_GET["func"];
$q=$_GET["q"];

switch($sFunction){
    case 'showCharacters':
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($q) . "'") or die(mysql_error());
    Display Info from Database.
    break;
    case 'showTowers':
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($q) . "'") or die(mysql_error());
    Display Info from Database.
    break;
    case 'showEnemies':
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($q) . "'") or die(mysql_error());
    Display Info from Database.
    break;
    }
?>
```

I've tried a few different things, although nothing has worked yet. One thing I tried is since the parameter is made into a variable at the start of the script, I made it into a string and tried the preg_replace expression, but that still had no effect. Maybe I didn't use the correct syntax? I'm not sure. I'm not very knowledgeable about PHP, but I'm sure I'm on the right track.

The parameter is passed to the script in this format: ("Number" func= "parentelement-name") = `2func=showTowers`

This is what I tried, although it didn't work.

```
$para =$_GET["q"];
$bres = (string)$para;
$ares = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $bres);
```

Any help is appreciated. Please don't comment about jquery or say anything negative about how dumb my question is. If it was really that dumb, I wouldn't be asking for help.

Comment: Also in your db querys you are using $q instead of $sQ

Comment: I forgot that I had changed that already. I edited my post to show it. I had it typed up correctly before, but when I was copying and pasting from separate versions of the files, that was a small difference between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not delimit your query variables with an ampersand, as you should. Do this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str+"&func="+ajaxFunction,true); 
                                         ^
                                         |
ADDED! ----------------------------------/
```

Comment: Firebug now tells me `func=showTowers, q=2` Which are the two parameters I needed so you fixed my issue, but it's still not getting a response from the server. I know the query is correct, because I used the same exactly line to access the database before on another page, but on that page, there are three separate ajax and three separate php scripts being ran which do the exact same thing as these two do. I was trying to make it to where it could run all 6 from 1 script each; 1 ajax and 1 php. Any idea why it's still not getting a response or a way I can find out why it isn't?

Comment: Looks like your php script is not returning anything.  Simpliest way is put some debug in your php code and call it directly in the browser - to see the output with the variables that are passed in.

Comment: I'll do that. Maybe I can figure this out myself. I should be able to even if I did start using php not even two weeks ago.